# how to use file_get_contents on foreach loop

Tags: php, web-crawler, file-get-contents

I am making a web crawler and want to get contents of a specific website. Here is the code so far.

```
<?php
include('libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
for ($x = 1; $x <= 1; $x++) {

    $pakwheels = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $x . '');

    $doc = new simple_html_dom();

    $doc->load($pakwheels);
    foreach($doc->find('a[class=car-name]') as $link)
    {
           $link->href = 'http://www.pakwheels.com' . $link->href;

            $details = file_get_contents($link);

            $pakfile = 'pakfile.txt';
            file_put_contents($pakfile , $details, FILE_APPEND);
    }   
}
?>
```

When I want to use `file_get_contents` it's showing me warnings and contents is not put in file. Any solution is highly appreciated.

[image]

When I echo the result like this:

```
<?php
include('libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
for ($x = 1; $x <= 1; $x++) {

    $pakwheels = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $x . '');

    $doc = new simple_html_dom();

    $doc->load($pakwheels);
    foreach($doc->find('a[class=car-name]') as $link)
    {
           $link->href = 'http://www.pakwheels.com' . $link->href;
            echo $link->outertext;

            //$details = file_get_contents($link);

            //$pakfile = 'pakfile.txt';
             //file_put_contents($pakfile , $details, FILE_APPEND);
    }   
}
?>
```

I get this which I want,

[image]

The thing which I want to achieve is `file_get_contents` to save each links details page on a file.

Comment: Hint, `file_get_contents()` takes a file path, or a URL string. It does not take HTML.

Comment: $link->href = 'http://www.pakwheels.com' . $link->href;

Comment: file_get_contents is getting data from a $link which you can see

Comment: Seriously? Look at your warning messages, look at your code. You're passing the anchor tag HTML into `file_get_contents()` I'm not sure how much more specific I can be! `$details = file_get_contents($link);`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Everyone.I did It myself.

```
<?php
```

include('libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
for ($x = 1; $x <= 1; $x++) {

```
$pakwheels = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $x . '');

$doc = new simple_html_dom();

$doc->load($pakwheels);
foreach($doc->find('a[class=car-name]') as $link)
{
      // $link->href = 'http://www.pakwheels.com' . $link->href;

        $details = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com'.$link->href);

        $pakfile = 'pakfile.txt';
         file_put_contents($pakfile , $details, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Excellent, Thanks friend, you have saved me a lot of work time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass an HTML markup to  `file_get_contents()`, Hence your code:

```
file_get_contents("<a href='http://example.com/file.php'></a<");
```

Would not work, you should put the url-string directly:

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/file.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

> $detail = file_get_contents($link);

Change to

> $detail = file_get_contents($link->href);